# How to actually reuse an app in Django?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-templates, django-views

Take for instance the polls app in the official Django tutorial, if for example I had a homepage and would like to make a sidebar containing a poll, how to I actually code it in relation to that homepage using the polls app? Which app should the homepage belong? There is absolutely no tutorial that exist anywhere.

Comment: Your question is very broad. For a more concise answer, we'll need a more specific question. In general, though, the app can be placed inside of another `project`, and the views/templates can be wired into existing applications via imports/template-includes

Comment: @Hybrid I have several app that needs to share a base.html, where do I put this base.html and how do I access it, do I create an app just to contain such core elements?

Comment: Create a file in 'templates/' called '_base.html' and include it at the top of html pages using '{% extends '_base.html' %}'